# Rails 3's link_to('&raquo;', url) won't work if it is &raquo; or other entities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

because it will not show up as `»` but will show up as `&raquo`.  Is there a way to show it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try:

`link_to "&raquo;".html_safe, url`